# Need help with using Player Prefs to save number of coins collected

Tags: unity, c#, savegame, user-interface

I'm using unity 3D to make a game where the character collides with coins in order to collect them. When playing the game, the player should start out with zero coins and each time he collides with a coin, the amount should increase by one. On a main menu scene, the total number of coins (that have been collected across multiple games) should be displayed. The total number of coins is being displayed on the main menu but once in the gameplay scene, the total number of coins is being displayed there too (where it's supposed to start at 0 and then increase by 1 each time a coin is collected). Here is the script I use for when the player collides with a coin:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider target)
    {
        CoinScoreManager.coinAmount += 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is the script I use to manage the UI and coin number in the game play scene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int coinAmount;
    public Text coinText;

    void Start()
    {

        coinAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CoinAmount");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        coinText.text = coinAmount.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CoinAmount", coinAmount);
    }
}
```

Here is the script I use to manage the UI and total coin number in the scene with the main menu:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainMenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    int coinAmount;
    public Text coinAmountText;

    void Start()
    {
        coinAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CoinAmount");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        coinAmountText.text = coinAmount.ToString();
    }

}
```

I think the problem is in the second script shown above. In the Start function I'm calling the coinAmount which is the same variable used to show the total coin number. I think that's the problem but I'm not really sure how to fix the problem as I'm still kinda of new to Unity and programming. Please let me know if there's anything else you need to know about the game in order to figure out how to fix this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things to improve, but that is expected from a new programmer. These are the tips for future:

- you should not be calling `PlayerPrefs` every single `Update` call. It just hogs performance. ...
- you should not trust static variables on counting stuff. Better approach would be to use [Singleton pattern](https://answers.unity.com/questions/891380/unity-c-singleton.html) (answer of AndresBarrera), and use its methods. ...
- do not set `Text` value on every `Update`. It will dirty whole canvas and it will force recalculation and redrawing, which might get expensive when your canvas contains many elements.

Keeping those points in mind, you should make your `CoinScoreManager` a singleton. It should retrieve current coins count in `Awake` and cache it to `private` variable. Then, provide methods for getting and setting that variable value.

Read about C# events and how they work. Create `public event Action<int> CoinAmountChanged` event on `CoinScoreManager` and subscribe to it from `MainMenuController`. `CoinScoreManager` should raise this event when coin amount is set through method. This will make coin text change only when coin amount changes. This is what we ultimately want, right?

I gave you directions, where and what to look for. Try figuring it out yourself. If it is still too hard to grasp the concept, I will edit my answer providing the code.

## THE CODE

#### CoinScoreManager.cs

```
public sealed class CoinScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string CoinAmountPrefName = "CoinAmount";

    public event Action<int> CoinAmountChanged;

    private int _coinAmount;
    
    public static CoinScoreManager Instance {get; private set;}

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)    // Checking if there's currently no active instance (singleton can only have one instance throughout lifespan of the program (game))
        {
            LoadCoinsAmount();
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"There's another instance of {nameof(CoinScoreManager)}. Destroying this script.);
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        CoinAmountChanged = null; // Clearing event subscribers to prevent memory leaks.
    }


    public void AddCoins(int count)
    {
        _coinAmount += count;

        CoinAmountChanged?.Invoke(_coinAmount);
        SaveCoinsAmount();
    }

    public int GetCoinsAmount()
    {
        return _coinAmount;
    }

    public void LoadCoinsAmount()
    {
        _coinAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(CoinAmountPrefName, 0);
    }

    public void SaveCoinsAmount()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(CoinAmountPrefName, _coinAmount);
    }
}
```

For this to work, you must add *CoinScoreManager* script on an active GameObject and the GameObject must not be child of any other objects.

#### CoinScript.cs

```
...
OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
    CoinScoreManager.Instance.AddCoins(1); // Calling singleton's method. Will throw exception if CoinScoreManager component is not present in the scene.
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
...
```

And now, making *MainMenuController* to only change after coin amount is changed.

#### MainMenuController.cs

```
public class MainMenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text coinAmountText;


    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (CoinScoreManager.Instance != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribing from event to prevent memory leaks
            CoinScoreManager.Instance.CoinsAmountChanged -= OnCoinsAmountChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Subscribing to CoinsAmountChanged event
        CoinScoreManager.Instance.CoinsAmountChanged += OnCoinsAmountChanged;

        // Making text value to be updated when script first starts
        OnCoinAmountChanged(CoinScoreManager.Instance.GetCoinsAmount());
    }

    private void OnCoinAmountChanged(int newAmount)
    {
        coinAmountText.text = newAmount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the correct solution but at the same time is way too complicated for a beginner (assuming he is a beginner when he still tries to understand how variables are filled). Maybe give him a hint more in the direction with what he has or why it is behaving like it is - actions/ subscribers, singletons and code optimization should wait until the basics are more solid. Adding more complex code that is not understood will be more counterproductive.

Comment: @Zibelas I was writing this answer with an idea to give directions to what aspects of C# should be learnt in future, mainly. I agree, I might have given too much in one answer, but as OP progresses in programming, he can return to this answer and check for further directions. Furthermore, more advanced users will see this answer and can improve their game design as well.

Comment: @TomasŠvedas I actually had a singleton in the code before I posted that question but I had no idea what it did and I didn't know that it was even called a singleton. It wasn't working so I deleted it and then tried what's posted above. I took your advice and I started researching how to use singletons, however, I'm still confused as to how I can actually use one in my code to make it run properly. Are you able to provide the code? Once I see how that works, I'll have a better understanding of how to use singletons as I'm pretty sure I'll need to use more singletons later on in this project.

Comment: Edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: @eLTomis Everything works well now, except for some reason when a coin is collected, it adds 2 to the score. I couldn't figure out why, but in "public int GetCoinsAmount()", I changed it from "return _coinAmount;" to "return _coinAmount / 2;". Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Mathesom you should look at your setup of colliders not just return amount/2... check if your coin or player game object doesn't contain two colliders. If it does, your `TriggerEnter` is called for each collider that has `isTrigger` checked.

Answer (score 0):

You see exactly what your code describes. You are storing in your PlayersPref your total amount of coins. You load this value when you start a game, it would be weird if you would not see the total amount. When a game starts, you don't want to load from your PlayersPref but just 0. You might want to introduce a second variable to your CoinScoreManager (currentGame) and display this value during your actual gameplay. When your game is over, you add this value to your coinAmount to update your mainmenu coin value and persist it.